# Difference between Request (Facade) and Illuminate\Http\Request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-request

I'm starting to use Laravel and I would like to know how I should choose one over the other.

As of version 5.0 Laravel documentation changed request example from `Request::get('form_input')` to `$request->get('form_input')`, but I couldn't find any explanation as for why they've done that.

My doubts are:

1. **Is there any difference between those `Requests`?**
2. **Whare are they?**
3. **What's the most prefered?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straigth answer: No (particular difference)
Except that: Referencing from this source, [How laravel facades work and how to use](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-laravel-facades-work-and-how-to-use-them-elsewhere/)

> A Laravel facade is a class which provides a static-like interface to services inside the container. These facades, according to the documentation, serve as a proxy for accessing the underlying implementation of the container’s services.

I couldn't agree more with this. But as for me, using facade pattern *simply make my code cleaner* :)

Answer (score 2):

The Request facade and the request() helper refer both to app('request') instance.
I think the examples in docs changed to $request because you can define your own Request derived class and the service container will automatically inject it in the action call, like in the case of FormRequest, i.e.:

```
public function store(UserStoreRequest $request)
{
    $name = $request->input('name');
```